# What is the difference between running a command directly and with `bash -c`?

Tags: bash

For a command (builtin or external), what is the difference of
    running it directly  in a bash shell process and with `bash -c` in
    the bash shell? What are their advantages and disadvantages
    comparing to each other?

```
For example, in a bash shell, run `date` directly, and run `bash -c
date`. Also consider a builtin command instead of an external one.
```

Answer (score 14):

1. The `-c` option allows programs to run commands. 
   It’s a lot easier to fork and do

   ```
   execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "date | od -cb  &&  ps > ps.out", NULL);
   ```

   than it is to fork, create a pipe, fork again,
   call `execl` in each child, call `wait`, check the exit status,
   fork again, call `close(1)`, open the file,
   ensure that it is open on file descriptor 1, and do another `execl`. 
   I believe that this was the reason why the option was created
   in the first place.

   The `system()` library function runs a command by the above method.
2. It provides a way to take an arbitrarily complex command
   and make it look like a simple command. 
   This is useful with programs that run a user-specified command,
   such as `find … -exec` or `xargs`. 
   But you already knew that; it was part of the answer to your question,
   [How to specify a compound command as an argument to another command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275441/80216#275456)
3. It can come in handy
   if you’re running an interactive shell other than bash. 
   Conversely, if you are running bash, you can use this syntax

   ```
   $ ash  -c "command"
                ︙
    
   $ csh  -c "command"
                ︙
    
   $ dash -c "command"
                ︙
    
   $ zsh  -c "command"
                ︙
   ```

   to run one command in another shell,
   as all of those shells also recognize the `-c` option. 
   Of course you could achieve the same result with

   ```
   $ ash
   ash$ command
           ︙
   ash$ exit
    
   $ csh
   csh$ command
           ︙
   csh$ exit
    
   $ dash
   dash$ command
           ︙
   dash$ exit
    
   $ zsh
   zsh$ command
           ︙
   zsh$ exit
   ```

   I used `ash$` , etc., to illustrate the prompts from the different shells;
   you probably wouldn’t actually get those.
4. It can come in handy
   if you want to run one command in a “fresh” bash shell; for example,

   ```
   $ ls -lA
   total 0
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gman gman   0 Apr 14 20:16 .file1
   -rw-r--r-- 1 gman gman   0 Apr 14 20:16 file2

   $ echo *
   file2

   $ shopt -s dotglob

   $ echo *
   .file1 file2

   $ bash -c "echo *"
   file2
   ```

   or

   ```
   $ type shift
   shift is a shell builtin

   $ alias shift=date

   $ type shift
   shift is aliased to ‘date’

   $ bash -c "type shift"
   shift is a shell builtin
   ```
5. The above is a misleading over-simplification. 
   When bash is run with `-c`, it is considered a *non-interactive* shell,
   and it does not read `~/.bashrc`, unless is `-i` specified.  So,

   ```
   $ type cp
   cp is aliased to ‘cp -i’          # Defined in  ~/.bashrc
    
   $ cp .file1 file2
   cp: overwrite ‘file2’? n
    
   $ bash -c "cp .file1 file2"
                                     # Existing file is overwritten without confirmation!
   $ bash -c -i "cp .file1 file2"
   cp: overwrite ‘file2’? n
   ```

   You could use `-ci`, `-i -c` or `-ic` instead of `-c -i`.

   This probably applies to some extent to the other shells
   mentioned in paragraph 3, so the long form (i.e., the second form,
   which is actually exactly the same amount of typing) might be safer, especially if you have initialization/configuration files
   set up for those shells.
6. As [Wildcard explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276595/135943), since you’re running a new process tree
   (a new shell process and, potentially, its child process(es)),
   changes to the environment made in the subshell
   *cannot* affect the parent shell (current directory,
   values of environment variables, function definitions, etc.) 
   Therefore, it’s hard to imagine a shell builtin command
   that would be useful when run by `sh -c`. 
   `fg`, `bg`, and `jobs` cannot affect or access background jobs
   started by the parent shell, nor can `wait` wait for them. 
   `sh -c "exec some_program"` is essentially equivalent
   to just running *`some_program`* the normal way,
   directly from the interactive shell. 
   `sh -c exit` is a big waste of time. 
   `ulimit` and `umask` could change the system settings
   for the child process, and then exit without exercising them.

   Just about the only builtin command that would be functional
   in a `sh -c` context is `kill`. 
   Of course, the commands that only produce output
   (`echo`, `printf`, `pwd` and `type`) are unaffected,
   and, if you write a file, that will persist.
7. Of course you can use a builtin *in conjunction with*
   an external command; e.g.,

   ```
   sh -c "cd some_directory; some_program"
   ```

   but you can achieve essentially the same effect with a normal subshell:

   ```
   (cd some_directory; some_program)
   ```

   which is more efficient. 
   The same (both parts) can be said for something like

   ```
   sh -c "umask 77; some_program"
   ```

   or `ulimit` (or `shopt`). 
   And since you can put an arbitrarily complex command after `-c` —
   up to the complexity of a full-blown shell script —
   you might have occasion to use any of the repertoire of builtins;
   e.g., `source`, `read`, `export`, `times`, `set` and `unset`, etc.

Comment: +1 except I think you go too far on builtins. To be clear `echo printf type pwd` are builtins; so are `set shopt shift read readarray mapfile trap declare/typeset export local let readonly unset` which don't affect the parent but may still be useful inside a moderately complicated `-c`.

Comment: What is your point?  Did you read my 6th bullet, where I said that builtins are useful in conjunction with external command(s)?  Are you saying that I should give more examples in bullet #6?

Comment: Thanks. [Someone said that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276587/what-kinds-of-commands-can-be-run-with-bash-c?noredirect=1#comment480572_276587) your reply also answered [another question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276587/674), but is that true?

Comment: @Tim: What question?  I see five question marks in that “question”.  OK, I’m kidding — *a little*.  What are you still unsure about?  I showed an example of `sh -c` being used with a complex command line including three programs, a pipe, a `&&`, and a redirection; I showed an example of it being used with a compound command line including a `cd`, a `;`, and a program; I showed an example of it being used with `exec`; and I said it could be used with builtins like `echo`, `kill`, `printf`, `pwd` and `type` (and also `exit`, `ulimit`, and `umask`).  What more do you want to know?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If you mean “Does it mean `execve()` can operate on a script?”, (1) that has nothing to do with `bash -c`, and (2) what research have you done?  The `execve` man page answers this, and a search of this site yields [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/61393/80216#61437), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200339/80216#200350), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214101/80216#214108), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268766/80216#268777), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/80216#87600), and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/98993/80216#98997).

Answer (score 7):

Running `bash -c "my command here"` vs. just running `my command here` is primarily different in that the former starts a subshell and the latter runs the commands in the current shell.

As far as built-in commands vs. external commands, it doesn't really relate—*anything* you can run in the current shell, you can run in a subshell.

There are a number of differences in the effects, however:

- Changes to the environment made in the subshell *cannot* affect the parent shell (current directory, values of environment variables, function definitions, etc.)
- Variables set in the parent shell that have not been exported will be unavailable in the subshell.

This is far from an exhaustive list of differences, but it contains the key point: you are running a different process with `bash -c`; it's not the same process as your original shell.

There is also a performance hit incurred by spawning a subshell; this is most relevant if your script is run frequently, or if your command is inside a loop of some kind.

Comment: FYI, I quoted your answer in my answer.  I tried to ping you from there, knowing that that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The -c option basically runs a mini-shell script provided as a CLI argument rather than a file.

```
$ bash -c the_script the_scriptname 1 2 3
```

is virtually equivalent to:

```
$ echo the_script > the_scriptname
$ bash the_scriptname 1 2 3
$ rm the_scriptname
```

As you can see from:

```
$ bash -c 'printf " ->%s\n" $0 "$@"; echo $-;' scriptname 1 2 3
   ->scriptname
   ->1
   ->2
   ->3
  hBc
```

(In English: 
     $0 == scriptname; $@ == (1 2 3);
     and bash will:
     **h**ash commands; perform **B**race expansion, and it has been run with the `-c` flag)

and:

```
 $ echo 'printf " ->%s\n" $0 "$@"; echo $-;' > scriptname
 $ bash scriptname 1 2 3 
 ->scriptname
 ->1
 ->2
 ->3
 hB
```

Answer (score -1):

> -c string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to
> the positional parameters, starting with $0.

This will solve your questions I guess

Comment: thanks. can you explain explicitly to my questions?