# bash -c and noninteractive shell

Tags: bash

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276611/674:

> When bash is run with -c, it is considered a non-interactive shell, and it does not read ~/.bashrc, unless is -i specified.

1. How is a non-interactive shell defined?

   - Is a non-interactive shell defined as a shell which can't accept input from stdin?
     For example `bash -c cat` can accept input from stdin.
   - Can a non-interactive shell output to stdout? For example, `bash -c date` can write to stdout.
2. Does `bash -c` (without additional `-i` option) always create a non-interactive shell?

Comment: I think you're overanalyzing it a little.

Comment: Did you read `man bash | grep -C5 -i interactive`?

Comment: Yes. @Lucas. I am not asking about how to start an interactive shell, and how to do a thing or two under an interactive shell. I am asking about its definition, or less accurately, what it means.

Comment: The manual is pretty clear: `LESS=+/'An  interactive  shell' man bash`. I suggest that you read it.

Answer (score 8):

I made some investigations. According to the source code of bash.

**TL;DR**

> How is a non-interactive shell defined?

- lack of commands history
- jobs are not supported
- no line editing feature
- errors gets line number
- no prompt
- execution is stopped after first error

> Does bash -c (without additional -i option) always create a
>   non-interactive shell?

Yes

**Longer version.**

This function is called when bash receives `-c` option.

`no_line_editing = 1` means that you can't edit your commands by using backspace.

`bash_history_reinit (0);` disables the history and commands auto completion.

```
static void
init_noninteractive ()
{
#if defined (HISTORY)
  bash_history_reinit (0);
#endif /* HISTORY */
  interactive_shell = startup_state = interactive = 0;
  expand_aliases = posixly_correct; /* XXX - was 0 not posixly_correct */
  no_line_editing = 1;
#if defined (JOB_CONTROL)
  /* Even if the shell is not interactive, enable job control if the -i or
     -m option is supplied at startup. */
  set_job_control (forced_interactive||jobs_m_flag);
#endif /* JOB_CONTROL */
}
```

Job control is disabled by default unless you force it with `-m`

```
 /* We can only have job control if we are interactive unless we                      
force it. */

  if (interactive == 0 && force == 0)
    {
      job_control = 0;
      original_pgrp = NO_PID;
      shell_tty = fileno (stderr);
    }
```

Syntax error messages contains line numbers.

```
/* Report a syntax error with line numbers, etc.
   Call here for recoverable errors.  If you have a message to print,
   then place it in MESSAGE, otherwise pass NULL and this will figure
   out an appropriate message for you. */
static void
report_syntax_error (message)
     char *message;
{
...
if (interactive == 0)
print_offending_line ();
...
}
```

Simple test

```
root@test:~# ;;
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
root@test:~# bash -c ';;'
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
bash: -c: line 0: `;;'
```

Prompt is not printed after command execution.

```
/* Issue a prompt, or prepare to issue a prompt when the next character
   is read. */
static void
prompt_again ()
{
  char *temp_prompt;

  if (interactive == 0 || expanding_alias ())   /* XXX */
    return;
```

Command execution is stopped after first error.

```
  /* Parse error, maybe discard rest of stream if not interactive. */
      if (interactive == 0)
        EOF_Reached = EOF;
```

Answer (score 3):

Within a shell session, there are a number of options on or of, like:

- are aliases are expanded
- is someone/something typing on STDIN
- is the completion system loaded
- if commands are stored in a history file
- which files files are sourced at the start of the shell

An interactive shell is a shell that has some of these characteristics. You can, however, switch those options on or off to your liking. Think of the word `interactive shell` as a collection of behaviors that we commonly understand to need for a shell to be interactive.

When you start a shell with `-i`, it gets a bit messy, as it generally indicates that you are messing with the system. It might be that some of these shell options will have another value than what one normally understands as an interactive shell.

So concretely, your example `bash -c cat` will not have completion enabled, will not store anything in history. I would not want to call that `interactive`, but you are free to do that if you would so incline.

Comment: Thanks! Best explanation ever of what mysterious "interactive shell" means.

Answer (score 1):

An interactive shell is defined as a shell that reads commands from stdin.

Whether or not a non-interactive shell that is "defined" to be interactive by using the `-i` option reads the `$ENV` file (`~/.*rc`) is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. Is the shell created by `bash -i -c` interactive or non-interactive? Also see the example `bash -c -i "cp .file1 file2"` and `bash -c "cp .file1 file2"` in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276611/674

Comment: The difference is a result of the fact that bash seems to read $ENV in case it is called with the  `-i` option. Inside the $ENV file, there seem to be `alias` definitions for `cp` that replace `cp` by something like `cp -i`. BTW: there is currently a discussion whether POSIX should forbid aliases to be turned on in scripts with POSIX issue 8 that will start it's development around autumn 2016.