# Passing command to bash from cmd.exe (WSL) not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm on a Windows 10 machine with Windows Subsystem for Linux enabled/configured (Ubuntu). To explain my problem let me present you with two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

1. I start a `cmd.exe` prompt
2. I run `bash` in the `cmd.exe` prompt
3. (inside `bash`) I run a given command, called `dwiextract` in my case (from a neuroimaging analysis software package)

Works fine suggesting a successful installation of the software package.

**Scenario 2:**

1. I start a `cmd.exe` prompt
2. I attempt to pass the exact same command directly to `bash` from `cmd.exe` by using the following syntax: `bash -c dwiextract`

I get `command not found`.

(Note I learned about `bash -c` [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) and have used it successfully in other occasions.)

The following image shows exactly what I've done:

[image: example_diagram]

**My question:** Shouldn't these two scenarios be equivalent. Why does Scenario 1 work and Scenario 2 does not work?

Many thanks.

Comment: Likely related: [bash -c and noninteractive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277130/bash-c-and-noninteractive-shell)

Comment: Running bash as an interactive shell (using -i option) solved my problem. Thanks steeldriver.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running bash as an interactive shell (using `-i` option) solved my problem.

That is: `bash -c -i <command>`.

Comment: ... because the `$PATH` was not the same in the two shells, and starting an interactive shell forces `bash` to read the `bashrc` file, where the `PATH` is set.

Comment: I had to use exactly this: `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 -u robert bash -c -i "cd /mnt/c/fastai2 && conda activate fastai2 && jupyter lab"`

Comment: I had tried all options from this thread and nothing works still it says: /bin/bash Command not found

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `... bash -c -i "..."` this worked well for me

```bsh
wsl -d Debian -u myname -e dwiextract
```

also with parameters

```
wsl -d Debian -u myname -e uname -a
```