# Running a command from cmd.exe using WSL

Tags: ubuntu, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am facing the same issue here: [Passing command to bash from cmd.exe (WSL) not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439151/passing-command-to-bash-from-cmd-exe-wsl-not-working)

Except that for me the solutions there do not work either.

I have WSL installed, and I am trying to run a command called "bet" from cmd.exe by

1. opening cmd.exe
2. typing `bash -c -i "bet"`

which throws an error:

```
Command 'bet' not found, did you mean:

  command 'bget' from deb ax25-tools (0.0.10-rc4-3build1)
  command 'bst' from deb buildstream (1.4.1-1)
  command 'beet' from deb beets (1.4.9-4)
  command 'btt' from deb blktrace (1.2.0-5)
  command 'bat' from deb bacula-console-qt (9.4.2-2ubuntu5)
  command 'ben' from deb ben (0.9.0ubuntu2)
  command 'fet' from deb fet (5.42.2-2build1)
  command 'eet' from deb libeet-bin (1.23.3-8)
  command 'net' from deb samba-common-bin (2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

When I try doing this by opening cmd.exe and typing bash, and then typing "bet" to the linux command line, it works fine.

I have also tried doing this with `wsl -e "bet"` however that also does not achieve what I'm trying to do. (The bet command receives additional parameters which I add to the end, but the command does not go through. The command does go through if I run bet from linux shell directly).

FYI: Bet is a brain extraction tool which comes with FSL (https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki)

Comment: Running a normal interactive `bash` shell in WSL, what does `type bet` return?

Comment: "When I try doing this by opening cmd.exe and typing bash, and then typing "bet" to the linux command line, it works fine."  When it works, then also note what `type bet` outputs, then use that in your `bash -c` command.

Comment: ```type bet``` returns ```bet is /usr/local/fsl/bin/bet``` @roaima @Kusalananda
the issue is I really need to call this command directly using "bet" because these commands are called from a seperate program/script. I am not the one writing these commands. It is a script. How can I make it so that ```bash -c -i "bet"``` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know nothing about Windows and its `cmd.exe`, this answer assumes a Unix environment.  WSL is, in most user-visible ways, a Unix environment.

If this is a question regarding the use of `cmd.exe`, then the question may find a more appropriate audience on [the SuperUser site](https://superuser.com).

The issue seems to be that the path to the `bet` executable is not in the search path for the non-interactive shell you are starting.

There are a few different solutions:

1. Use the exact pathname of the executable:

   ```bash
   bash -c '/usr/local/fsl/bin/bet'
   ```
2. Change the `PATH` variable's value inside the `bash -c` script, before calling `bet`:

   ```bash
   bash -c 'PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/fsl/bin; bet'
   ```
3. Append the appropriate directory path to the `PATH` environment variable when you start the `bash -c` command.  This could be done in either of these ways:

   ```bash
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/fsl/bin bash -c bet
   ```

   ```bash
   env PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/fsl/bin" bash -c bet
   ```
4. Append the appropriate directory path to the `PATH` environment variable by modifying the current shell's environment.  This would be done by adding the following to one's shell's startup files (typically `~/.bash_profile` for the `bash` shell):

   ```bash
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/fsl/bin
   ```

   This would take effect with the next login shell session.  Then use

   ```bash
   bash -c bet
   ```
5. In the question, you also include the `-i` option when you start the `bash -c` command.  This would make the shell an interactive shell, and it would parse the `~/.bashrc` file.  Another option would therefore be to add

   ```bash
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/fsl/bin
   ```

   to the `~/.bashrc` file, but be aware that the purpose of this file is to set up the shell for interactive work, which may include running commands you don't want to run every time you start `bet`.  As an alternative, you can therefore add the above variable assignment to a brand new file and then start `bash` with

   ```bash
   bash -i --rcfile envfile -c bet
   ```

   ... where `envfile` is the new file.
6. If you have a file with the assignment mentioned in the previous point, you may start `bash` in one of the following ways

   ```bash
   BASH_ENV=envfile bash -c bet
   ```

   ```bash
   env BASH_ENV="envfile" bash -c bet
   ```

   Doing so would avoid having to run `bash` as an interactive shell (apart from parsing `~/.bashrc` by default, running the shell in interactive mode has other implications for the shell, like enabling job control).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solution 5. worked best for me!

Additionally, I needed to also add these inside ```~/.bashrc```
Such as:
```# FSL Setup FSLDIR=/usr/local/fsl PATH=${FSLDIR}/bin:${PATH} export FSLDIR PATH 
. ${FSLDIR}/etc/fslconf/fsl.sh```